# Jersey-client, how to print the POST request

Tags: java, post, multipart, jersey-client

I have this Jersey-client POST request:

```
MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart();
multiPart.bodyPart(new BodyPart(inParams.toString(), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE));
final File fileToUpload = new File(filePath);
multiPart.bodyPart(new BodyPart(fileToUpload, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE));

final ClientResponse clientResp = resource.type("multipart/form-data").post(ClientResponse.class, multiPart);
```

Is there  way I can print the actual request, I expect to get something like :

```
    ----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content"

    {"SP_PROT_SENDER":"","SP_PROT_IN":"0","FILENAME":"testRest.rar"}
    ----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="a"; filename="testRest.rar"
    Content-Type: 
    (...)

    ----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already solved this, but I ran into this the other day and found that the easiest way was to sniff the posted traffic with Netcat.

Here's how:

1. Make the URL you're posting use some obscure port number not used by anything else, like `15734`.
2. In another terminal window, type `nc -kl 15734`.
3. Trigger the request. The request will be printed in the above terminal window.

Things like GZip compression and chunking can make the output look weird, so you might want to turn those features off.